# does WMI cache data in requests?

Tags: wmi

I've tried the Win32_DesktopMonitor and checked the "Availability", but the value returned is always 3 (powered on), even when the monitor is physically turned off.

Is the data cached and there's a "force refresh" command in WMI, or in this particular case, the "Availability" is just not reliable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look to your driver. According to the documentation, starting with Windows Vista, hardware that is not compatible with Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) returns inaccurate property values for instances of this class. For me it's an another way to say that it's not reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is caching going on somewhere.  I've observed it recently.

I wrote code that was polling for updates to Win32_PnPSignedDriver via SelectQuery / ManagementObjectSearcher and the results appear to be cached because it never realizes that a new device/driver has been added.  Running the query from a separate app instantly sees that it was updated.